# How do I click links in Visual Studio summaries?

Tags: visual-studio

I feel like this should be obvious, and perhaps I'm totally missing something, but how do I click URLs from **summaries**?

Below is a screenshot example of what I am talking about. (Obviously in this case since it is a warning I can copy the warning from the error list window, paste it into a text editor, extract the url, then use my browser. In other cases I would have to printscreen and then manually re-type the url. Either way, both these approaches are time consuming)

[image]

The "other cases" would be a result of viewing a summary from other binaries, where the developer used summary tags i.e.

```
/// <summary>
/// Visit http://www.google.com for more info
/// </summary>        
static void foo()
{
}
```

I cannot mouse over the summary box to click the link without it disappearing.

**EDIT**
I'm not griping that I cannot use an external browser, I can't click the link (or copy easily) from the summary box. There has to be a better way

Comment: Have you tried `Ctrl+Click` ?

Comment: What 'other cases' are you referring to?

Comment: @EdwindeKoning
In cases where URLs are part of summary tags like 
`/// <summary>/// Visit http://www.google.com for more info
        /// </summary>        
        static void foo()
        {
            
        }`

Comment: @Nacereddine
Yes, I am familiar with ctrl+click for use with URLs in comments, but I can't mouse over the box without it disappearing (as it appeared when I moused over the AddItemsCore routine

Comment: @James The least painful way I found to this is to press `F12` (Go to declaration) then `Ctrl+Click` the link there. Hope this helps if you don't find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was asked before, the only way to do it is with a macro (see below). You think Microsoft would make this easier.

```
Sub OpenURLInChrome()
'copy to end of line
DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.EndOfLine(True)

'set var
Dim url As String = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text

'launch chrome with url
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + "\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", url)
End Sub
```

Comment: This would work if I was able to select the text, which I cannot from a summary box.

Comment: @James I am not able to replicate the exact popup you are getting but normally just put my courser before the url. Reading your post more closely it looks like its not letting you do that. Are you running XP or Win7?

Comment: @JesseHauf to replicate his pop up use [this](http://pastebin.com/tYkJ5WK7) code then hover over `base.AddItemsCore(value);` with the cursor.

Comment: @James Ahhh, I simply right-click copy the message from the warning/error log and paste it into the URL bar. Then just delete the prefix and suffix. Although that takes just as long as Nacereddine's method.